# How do I add Book Title to running headers in scrbook?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrbook

I am trying to get this layout effect:
(Please ignore font)
[image: Required layout]

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,paper=a6,headings=small,titlepage=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lehead{Magnum Opus}
\automark{chapter}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \mainmatter
    \begin{center}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \vspace*{50px}
        {\Huge{Mangnum Opus}}\\
        \vspace*{25px}
        \em{Sum Boddhi}
    \end{center}
    \tableofcontents
    \addchap{Beginning}
    \kant
    \addchap{Middle}
    \kant
    \addchap{End}
    \kant
\end{document}
```

As can be seen it fulfils the Book Title condition but omits the Chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `\rohead{\rightmark}` is used. To get the desired result you have to set `\rohead{\leftmark}`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,paper=a6,headings=small,titlepage=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\automark{chapter}
\lehead{Magnum Opus}
\rohead{\leftmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{50px}
        {\Huge{Mangnum Opus}}\\
        \vspace*{25px}
        \em{Sum Boddhi}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Beginning}
\kant
\addchap{Middle}
\kant
\addchap{End}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use `\automark[chapter]{chapter}`. Then `\chapter` sets the right and the left mark:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,paper=a6,headings=small,titlepage=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\lehead{Magnum Opus}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{50px}
        {\Huge{Mangnum Opus}}\\
        \vspace*{25px}
        \em{Sum Boddhi}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Beginning}
\kant
\addchap{Middle}
\kant
\addchap{End}
\kant
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

---

If the chapter name should be in header of chapter pages too, add

```
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}
```